# CSS adjacent sibling selector doesn't work

Tags: html, css

this code is supposed to display the "container-1" div every time I hover on the "container" div. However, it isn't acting like I want it to since instead of it displaying block every hover, it just stays to display:none

CSS Code

```
.container:hover + .container-1 {
  display: block;
  color:blue
}

.container-1{
 display: none;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 12px 0;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="container-1">
        <p><b>$167</b> still needed for this project</p>
    </div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="w3-light-grey" id="bar">
            <div class="w3-orange" style="height: 18px;width:75%"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="box-1">
            <p>
                <span>
                    <b style="color:orange;">Only 3 days left</b> to fund this project
                </span><br>
                <span>
                    Join the <b>42</b> other donors who have already supported this project. Ever dollar helps.
                </span>
            </p>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="field">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Give Now"><br>
                <span><b style="color:rgb(110, 200, 235);">Why give $50?</b></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: container-1 needs to come after container if it is to be influenced by hovering on container. How fixed is the design? The obvious thing to do is just move container-1 to after container. The problem with (visually) placing it before is that container would move down and you'll get flashing on the hover. Is it OK to reserve space above container?

Answer (score 0):

The adjacent sibling selector (`+`) is used to select an element that is **directly after** another specific element.

Sibling elements must have the same **parent element**, and adjacent means immediately following not preceding

---

Just put the `.container-1` at the bottom of `.container`. And now it will be the adjacent sibling of `.container` element.

---

**This will do the Work -**

```css
.container:hover + .container-1 {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}

.container-1 {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="w3-light-grey" id="bar">
    <div class="w3-orange" style="height: 18px;width:75%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <p>
      <span><b style="color:orange;">Only 3 days left</b> to fund this project</span>
        <br>
      <span>Join the <b>42</b> other donors who have already supported this project. Ever dollar helps.</span>
    </p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="field">
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Give Now"><br>
      <span><b style="color:rgb(110, 200, 235);">Why give $50?</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-1">
  <p><b>$167</b> still needed for this project</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.container-1` comes *before* `.container` in terms of the HTML. The best way to get around this would be to swap the positioning of the two HTML elements, then put `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` on the parent (in this case, `<body>`):

```css
.container:hover+.container-1 {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}

.container-1 {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="w3-light-grey" id="bar">
    <div class="w3-orange" style="height: 18px;width:75%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <p>
      <span><b style="color:orange;">Only 3 days left</b> to fund this project</span><br>
      <span>Join the <b>42</b> other donors who have already supported this project. Ever dollar helps</span>
    </p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="field">
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Give Now"><br>
      <span><b style="color:rgb(110, 200, 235);">Why give $50?</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-1">
  <p><b>$167</b> still needed for this project</p>
</div>
```

Note, however, that the addition of the new element pushes the `.container` element down the page, meaning that the user may no longer be hovering over it. This may result in some undesirable 'flashing'.